# Msvc compiles &(Class::mem) but gcc does not

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

I have recently learnt about pointer to member syntax and then wrote the program shown below that msvc compiles but gcc and clang rejects.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> 
#include <concepts>
struct C
{
    int foo()
    {
    return 5;
    }
};
int main()
{ 
      int (C::*ptr)() = &(C::foo);   //msvc compiles but not gcc and clang  
}
```

I want to know which one is correct. [Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7xK7saGaM)

Comment: `C::foo` is already a pointer to the member function.

Comment: The problem is those parens.  Just do `&C::foo` and g++ will accept it, although the `&` is optional for functions.

Comment: gcc and clang are correct. Pointer to member function can only be written in the form `&Class::mem`. No parenthesis are allowed.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Yes according to the current wording it is ill-formed but [P2904](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2904r0.pdf) proposes that **this exception in normal precedence rules be removed** and the program be well-formed.

Comment: @user12002570 Then I'm really interested in why this was **explicitly** disallowed in the first place. The same question is also raised in P2904. Although maybe this should be a separate question.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Yes, that's exactly what [P2904] asks, in particular it has a line saying: *"is there a reason why the normal operator precedence rules are not applied here"*.

Comment: @user207421 No, the standard does not allow using simply `C::foo` to create a pointer to *member* (unlike what is the case with non-member functions). The proper syntax is `&C::foo`. Although MSVC allows `C::foo`, it is a Microsoft's extension, and you'll get an error [C3867](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3867?view=msvc-170) if you'll try to use it in the recent versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: `ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.  Say '&C::foo' ` Yeah that's correct, MSVC is being MSVC, following Microsoft own standard "we can't changed it , it breaks code some moron had wrote and we aren't allowed to change it". There is a reason why `__clusplus` is incorrect in that compiler. Or that in older compilers , befor 2013, an inherited dafault constructor was replaced by user-defined no-op constructor, leading to uninitialized members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [P2904](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2904r0.pdf) which **proposes** that the program be well-formed.

Note again that **as per the current wording the program is ill-formed** but the above paper proposes to make it well-formed by removing the exception in the normal precedence rules. Here is the relevant change in the wording as proposed by the paper:

##### Change in wording

*Change [expr.unary.op#4] to as shown below:*

A pointer to member is <s>only</s> formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a qualified-id <s>not enclosed in parentheses</s>.

[Note 4: <s>That is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed in
parentheses, does not form an expression of type pointer to member . Neither does.</s> The
expression qualified-id does not form an expression of type pointer to member, be-
cause there is no implicit conversion from a qualified-id for a non-static member function
to the type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of function type to
the type “pointer to function” ([conv.func]). <s>Nor</s> Neither is &unqualified-id a pointer
to member, even within the scope of the unqualified-id’s class. — end note]

Comment: Uh, that proposal fails to address the case when both `&A::x` and `&(A::x)` compile and have different meanings: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xPhfE9csn

Comment: @HolyBlackCat In your above [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xPhfE9csn), shouldn't `&(A::x)` be still ill-formed as per the current wording, so this seems to be the first reason for the demo(your version) to not compile? Also as the paper proposes `&A::x` should be treated as `&(A::x)` so there is this second reason(which P2904 proposes) also for the demo to not compile?

Comment: `&(A::x)` is taking the address of the member `x` in the `A` base-class subobject. There is no reason to make it ill-formed.

Comment: *"&(A::x) is taking the address of the member x in the A base-class subobject."* Yes but that's what `&A::x` is also supposed to do. In any case, the point I think is to make them behave the same and obey the normal operator precedence rules.

Comment: You're the author of that proposal, aren't you? I don't see why `&(A::x)` would be ill-formed, http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3 says it should fall back to making a non-member pointer. *"the paper proposes &A::x should be treated as &(A::x) so there is this second reason(which P2904 proposes) also for the demo to not compile?"* I don't understand what you're saying here. You propose the opposite, to treat `&(A::x)` as `&A::x`, assuming that the former was always ill-formed anyway. But there are cases where it's legal and has different meaning.

Comment: "Yes but that's what `&A::x` is also supposed to do." No. In the link above, `&A::x` is a pointer-to-member. `&(A::x)` is a plain pointer.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I think you misinterpreted when I said *"so there is this second reason(which P2904 proposes) also for the demo to not compile?"* which I can understand as comments have a word limit so I did not completely said why it is ill-formed according to the paper. What I meant was that since the paper proposes `&A::x` and `&(A::x)` are completely equivalent, so the `static_assert` in your demo should fail. That is, the demo should not compile since the static asserts test two different things. I was not saying that `&(A::x)` be ill-formed.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I know that already. My point was that the demo should fail since the static assert is testing different things(`&A::x` is a pointer-to-member. `&(A::x)` is a plain pointer in that demo.) But the paper proposes that they(`&A::x` and `&(A::x)`) are treated the same so that the demo should fail.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Whatever be the case(as you're free to believe in any fairy tail), `&A::x` should be equivalent to `&(A::x)`, that's the point of the paper.

Comment: No language rule mandates that `&A::x` is equivalent to `&(A::x)` and now we have a reason why they **should not** be equivalent. In particular, in `&A::x`, `A::x` is not an expression, so the justification in the paper using operator precedence for expressions does not really work. I actually had a comment saying that this is similar to how `(func)(x)` and `func(x)` can do different things in the question but I removed it.

Comment: *"In particular, `A::x` is not an expression..."* **What?** Why is `A::x` not an expression when it can be used as one? See [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GMWodGra5). I think you're the one who is confused.

Comment: @WeijunZhou `So now I'm inclined to believe that the author of the paper is confused` or they are from Microsoft.  That happened a few times with  C++11 daft where they were trying to push  their compiler's features into standard. Afaik only lambda functions were semi-success , even though rules had changed slightly.

Comment: I stand corrected. I originally thought the special treatment was introduced at syntactic level which causes `&A::x` to be parsed and tokenized differently from just `unary operator` + `expression`. Turns out it is only the semantic interpretation is different. So indeed I'm the one that's confused. Still, if the proposal is followed, there would not be a valid syntax for pointer-to-member in your example.

Comment: @user12002570 _"In particular, A::x is not an expression..." **What?**_ In `auto px = &C::x;`, what is the `C::x`'s [result](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.lval#def:result,glvalue)?

Comment: @user12002570 _See demo_ How does it prove `C::x` is an expression? `C::x` is transformed into `(*this).C::x` in that context, and this whole thing is an expression. However, it is somewhat agreed that `E2` in `E1.E2` should not be an expression (https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/2876#issuecomment-575804663)

Answer (score 8):

The code is ill-formed, MSVC is wrong.

[`[expr.unary.op]/3`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#3)

> If the operand is a *qualified-id* naming a non-static or variant member `m` of some class `C`, other than an explicit object member function, the result has type “pointer to member of class `C` of type `T`” and designates `C::​m`.
>
> Otherwise, the result has type “pointer to `T`” ...

In `&(C::foo)`, `(C::foo)` is not a *qualified-id* (`C::foo` would be one), but rather a [*primary-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#nt:primary-expression).

Also [`[expr.unary.op]/4`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#4) is even more explicit:

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit `&` is used and its operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses.

The rationale behind this is to have a syntax for forming a regular (non-member) pointer, in case you need one (as opposed to a member-pointer):

```
#include <type_traits>

struct A
{
    int x;
};

struct B : A
{
    int x;

    void foo()
    {
        auto f = &A::x;
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(f), int A::*>);

        auto g = &(A::x);
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(g), int *>);
    }
};
```

MSVC also accepts this code, so I guess they're only being non-conformant for member functions, not data members (which isn't a big deal, since for member functions `&(C::foo)` is otherwise always illegal).

Comment: _In `&(C::foo)`, `(C::foo)` is not a qualified-id (`C::foo` would be one), but rather a primary-expression_ Neither `C::foo` in `&C::foo` a _qualified-id_, but rather a _cast-expression_ (http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.general#nt:unary-expression). Also, http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.paren#1.sentence-2. Saying _qualified-id_ is not «otherwise indicated». http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary.op#4.sentence-1 is.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Thanks, added that quote from `[expr.unary.op]/4`. (I think I would've understood `[expr.unary.op]/3` as "otherwise indicated" too...) *"Neither C::foo in &C::foo a qualified-id, but rather a cast-expression"* It's both a cast-expression and a qualified-id (cast-expression -> unary-expression -> postfix-expression -> primary-expression -> id-expression -> qualified-id). Otherwise that part of `[expr.unary.op]/3` would be meaningless.